# fldigi will only start the second/third time

Tags: fldigi

Starting sometimes after 2nd sometimes after 3th times.
Just now PC fresh booted, then console and fldigi started.

1. and 2. start hangs after the two messages "Silicon_Labs_CP2105_Dual_...."
2. start works, see now the successful ended start sequence below (in parts).

It has something to do with the ALSA Sound.

---

```
hb9fih@hb9fih-HP-EliteBook-840-G1:~$ fldigi
I: main: appname: fldigi
I: main: HomeDir: /home/hb9fih/.fldigi/
I: main: RigsDir: /home/hb9fih/.fldigi/rigs/
I: main: ScriptsDir: /home/hb9fih/.fldigi/scripts/
I: main: PalettesDir: /home/hb9fih/.fldigi/palettes/
I: main: LogsDir: /home/hb9fih/.fldigi/logs/
I: main: PicsDir: /home/hb9fih/.fldigi/images/
I: main: HelpDir: /home/hb9fih/.fldigi/help/
I: main: MacrosDir: /home/hb9fih/.fldigi/macros/
I: main: WrapDir: /home/hb9fih/.fldigi/wrap/
I: main: TalkDir: /home/hb9fih/.fldigi/talk/
I: main: TempDir: /home/hb9fih/.fldigi/temp/
I: main: LoTWDir: /home/hb9fih/.fldigi/LOTW/
I: main: KmlDir: /home/hb9fih/.fldigi/kml/
I: main: PskMailDir: /home/hb9fih/
I: main: DATA_dir: /home/hb9fih/.fldigi/data/
I: main: NBEMS_dir: /home/hb9fih/.nbems/
I: main: ARQ_dir: /home/hb9fih/.nbems/ARQ/
I: main: ARQ_files_dir: /home/hb9fih/.nbems/ARQ/files/
I: main: ARQ_recv_dir: /home/hb9fih/.nbems/ARQ/recv/
I: main: ARQ_send: /home/hb9fih/.nbems/ARQ/send/
I: main: WRAP_dir: /home/hb9fih/.nbems/WRAP/
I: main: WRAP_recv_dir: /home/hb9fih/.nbems/WRAP/recv/
I: main: WRAP_send_dir: /home/hb9fih/.nbems/WRAP/send/
I: main: WRAP_auto_dir: /home/hb9fih/.nbems/WRAP/auto/
I: main: ICS_dir: /home/hb9fih/.nbems/ICS/
I: main: ICS_msg_dir: /home/hb9fih/.nbems/ICS/messages/
I: main: ICS_tmp_dir: /home/hb9fih/.nbems/ICS/templates/
I: main: FLMSG_dir: /home/hb9fih/.nbems/
I: main: FLMSG_dir_default: /home/hb9fih/.nbems/
I: main: FLMSG_WRAP_dir: /home/hb9fih/.nbems/WRAP/
I: main: FLMSG_WRAP_recv_dir: /home/hb9fih/.nbems/WRAP/recv/
I: main: FLMSG_WRAP_send_dir: /home/hb9fih/.nbems/WRAP/send/
I: main: FLMSG_WRAP_auto_dir: /home/hb9fih/.nbems/WRAP/auto/
I: main: FLMSG_ICS_dir: /home/hb9fih/.nbems/ICS/
I: main: FLMSG_ICS_msg_dir: /home/hb9fih/.nbems/ICS/messages/
I: main: FLMSG_ICS_tmp_dir: /home/hb9fih/.nbems/ICS/templates/
I: testCommPorts: Found serial port /dev/serial/by-id/usb-Silicon_Labs_CP2105_Dual_USB_to_UART_Bridge_Controller_00733873-if00-port0
I: testCommPorts: Found serial port /dev/serial/by-id/usb-Silicon_Labs_CP2105_Dual_USB_to_UART_Bridge_Controller_00733873-if01-port0
**ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:618:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1052:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1052:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Cannot connect to server socket err = Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock**
I: rigCAT_init: 
Serial port parameters:
device   : /dev/serial/by-id/usb-Silicon_Labs_CP2105_Dual_USB_to_UART_Bridge_Controller_00733873-if00-port0
baudrate   : 19200
stopbits   : 1
retries : 2
timeout : 500
wait       : 5
initial rts: -12
use rts ptt: F
initial dtr: -12
use dtr ptt: F
restore tio: T
flowcontrol: T
echo       : F

I: rigCAT_init: Passed serial port test
I: rigCAT_init: Created rigCAT thread
initOptionMenus()
adding mode: LSB
adding mode: USB
adding mode: CW-USB
adding mode: FM
adding mode: AM
adding mode: RTTY-LSB
adding mode: CW-LSB
adding mode: DATA-LSB
adding mode: RTTY-USB
adding mode: DATA-FM
adding mode: FM-N
adding mode: DATA-USB
adding mode: AM-N
I: initInterface: using rigCAT xcvr control
I: readFreqList: # rfcarrier rig_mode carrier mode usage
I: readFreqList: 1000500 USB 800 CW 
I: readFreqList: 1807000 USB 1000 BPSK31 
I: readFreqList: 3505000 USB 800 CW 
I: readFreqList: 3580000 USB 1000 BPSK31 
I: readFreqList: 7005000 USB 800 CW 
I: readFreqList: 7030000 USB 1000 BPSK31 
I: readFreqList: 7070000 USB 1000 BPSK31 
I: readFreqList: 10135000 USB 1000 BPSK31 
I: readFreqList: 14005000 USB 800 CW 
I: readFreqList: 14070000 USB 1000 BPSK31 
I: readFreqList: 18100000 USB 1000 BPSK31 
I: readFreqList: 21005000 USB 800 CW 
I: readFreqList: 21070000 USB 1000 BPSK31 
I: readFreqList: 24920000 USB 1000 BPSK31 
I: readFreqList: 28005000 USB 800 CW 
I: readFreqList: 28120000 USB 1000 BPSK31 
**Expression 'alsa_snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format( pcm, hwParams, Pa2AlsaFormat( hostFormat ) )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1789**
I: loadDefault: macro file name: /home/hb9fih/.fldigi/macros/macros.mdf
I: loadDefault: loading: /home/hb9fih/.fldigi/macros/macros.mdf
I: loadDefault: /home/hb9fih/.fldigi/macros/macros.mdf
I: n3fjp_init: N3FJP logger thread started
I: open: Trying [127.0.0.1]:7322
I: do_readfile: logfile: /home/hb9fih/.fldigi/logs/logbook.adif, read 3 records in  0.0 seconds
I: FD_init: fdserver thread started
I: DXcluster_init: dxserver thread started
I: open: Trying [127.0.0.1]:1100
I: n3fjp_start: Client socket 51
I: delayed_startup: 
Portaudio devices:
HDA Intel HDMI: 0 (hw:0,3)
HDA Intel HDMI: 1 (hw:0,7)
HDA Intel HDMI: 2 (hw:0,8)
HDA Intel HDMI: 3 (hw:0,9)
HDA Intel HDMI: 4 (hw:0,10)
HDA Intel PCH: 92HD91BXX Analog (hw:1,0)
USB Audio CODEC: - (hw:3,0)
hdmi
pulse
default
```

When I start it the first time and it fails:

```
I: testCommPorts: Found serial port /dev/serial/by-id/usb-Silicon_Labs_CP2105_Dual_USB_to_UART_Bridge_Controller_00733873-if00-port0
I: testCommPorts: Found serial port /dev/serial/by-id/usb-Silicon_Labs_CP2105_Dual_USB_to_UART_Bridge_Controller_00733873-if01-port0
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:618:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1052:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1052:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Cannot connect to server socket err = Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
I: rigCAT_init: 
.......................................
```

Comment: what does the console show for the second time?

Comment: Tnx for try to help me Marcus.
Starting sometimes after 2nd sometimes after 3th times.
Just now PC fresh booted, konsole and fldigi started.
1. and 2. hangs after

Comment: Hi Marcus, I changed the question see there,
TNX

Comment: Um, you somehow deleted what it prints when you start it the first time – we need both to compare it!

Comment: Tried to fix that form the edit history. Um, are the `............` really there in that output or are you using these to signal an omission? This doesn't look like it fails because of ALSA, necessarily.

Comment: noo the ........... is my add.. says no more is comming....from here it has more lines but all goes trough without any error

Comment: if this hangs then the ALSA lib PCM not to see - there hangs.
(Stops after the 2 testComPort Lines)

Comment: Sorry, can you upload the **unaltered** full output somewhere? It's really confusing at this point. A good place to upload logs is https://fpaste.org. The errors you see (and which you think are fatal) are very likely not related to the problem you're having, otherwise the thing would abort earlier.

Comment: OK I puted them into my Blog:

http://www.hb9fih.org/?p=p_643&sName=fldigi-log

Comment: thanks... fpaste would have been easier for the raw text, but this works.

Comment: No, this doesn't work; this misses the "Found serial port…" and other messages. Did you **really** give us the full, unaltered output?

Comment: https://paste.centos.org/view/008ed303
this is the succesful start 
Yes there where all lines copied on my page. in unsucessful and sucessful

Comment: but in your post here, there's a line "Found serial port", and that is missing from your blog entry! So, could you also upload the output of the failing start to fpaste?

Comment: OK done 
https://paste.centos.org/view/9d1876ec

MNY TNX for ur help

Comment: Yes I  recognized the failure in my Blog....It is when I forget to plug in the USB to the TX... sri

Comment: Interesting: Yesterday I made the big update (new version on Linux MINT MATE to 19.3) and since fldigi starts first time.
The failure with ALSA ... also occours but the script does not hang/stop and fldigi start with CAT and AUDIO correctly.
Maybe any fix was done in the UpDate.

Comment: as said, these are just non-fatal warnings and probably have nothing to do with your problem. Just because ALSA prints something doesn't mean ALSA's at fault.

Comment: Anyway TNX for helping me.
Problem solved (we do not know why (must we know all?)  - whatever it runs..
MXMAS Erich

Answer (score 1):

This question appears to be answered on stack overflow here :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31603555/unknown-pcm-cards-pcm-rear-pyaudio

Comment: whereas the error messages from the post you link to reference bluetooth audio devices, these don't. So, I don't think this is related.